# Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object after installing custom template

Tags: magento

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 555
```

Installed Magento 1.7 and WAMP 2.2 and a custom template.  Magento admin works perfect but the frontend gives the above errors.

Page.xml in magento 1.7 installation and the custom template doesn't have the following code at all and therefore, didn't try the following fix :

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml"/>
```

would become:

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
```

Comment: did you try clearing /var/cache folder after that update in your page.xml...?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the core/profiler block doesn't exist in any of the page.xml files in my Magento installation and Custom template and therefore, did not touch these files.  However, everytime I modify any code, I turn off/disabled all cache storage, flush Magento Cache, flush Catalog Images Chache and flush Javascrip/CSS Cache and refresh frontend but the problem remains as-is.

Comment: Sudhir, I am not familiar with /var/cache cleanup procedure, so please explain.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

After changing:

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml"/>
```

to

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
```

in page.xml under **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout (or your custom page.xml)** 
either:
 refresh the cache in Layout building instructions from admin or
delete contents of **/var/cache** folder, which is located at root of your magento folder

Comment: I have two page.xml files, one in Magento 1.7 base/default/layout folder and it already contains the correct block.  However, another page.xml file in my Template default/layout folder doesn't contain <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml"/> instead it has <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">, so do you want me to delete this and replace it with <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>, Thanks to answer.
and therefore I didn't touch these files.

Comment: are you using magento default theme or you have custom theme, if using custom theme then yes try replacing/adding the custom theme's page.xml's core/profiler block with the new code i added in answer.. hope that works

Comment: Sudhir, using a custom theme.  I replaced <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml"> with <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/> and cleared var/cache, refreshed, gives a blank page without any error messages.

Comment: i meant either replace the block if you have block type="core/profiler" .. in your new theme else try adding that block not replacing <block type="page/html" ... with it, try adding that block

Comment: Sudhir, added <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/> and cleared var/cache, refreshed, again gives a blank page without any error messages

Comment: -->
After this edit, page.xml looks like this : <layout version="0.1.0">
<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->
    <default>
 <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml"> 
        <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
 <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">